# Nuxt3 receiving SSE from the backend

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-sent-events

I m trying to handle SSE in the frontend developped using Nuxt3
I didn t find any material that explains how to do it
Any help?

I searched for tutorial, i looking for a module to handle this subject

Comment: What did you tried so far? What is not working? We need more effort on your side here. Also, I'm not sure that [Server Sent Events](https://javascript.info/server-sent-events) is specific to Nuxt or alike. It's a vanilla API, so you can use it like that, nothing more needed.